# GUPSHUP endpoint for Wallet balance

Tags: gupshup

Is there an endpoint in API that will return the Wallet balance in U$ in the GUPshup?

I need to check the balance, without having to enter Gupshup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use the below API to get wallet balance:

```
curl --location --request GET 'https://api.gupshup.io/sm/api/v2/wallet/balance' \
--header 'apikey: {{APIKey}}'
```

For more details refer to this FAQ: https://support.gupshup.io/hc/en-us/articles/360017175260